# Programmaticaly force screen to light up in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I want my application according to some event, it comes to the background and light up the screen so the user notice that the blackberry has something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Backlight](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Backlight.html) API like this:
`Backlight.enable(true, timeInMs)`

Edit: you can even add a vibration with `Alert.startVibrate(timeInMs)`